# Are linked lists better than arrays for adding/removing elements at any position in the list?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list

I've been taught that in general, adding and deleting from a linked list tends to be better, as memory never has to be moved to accommodate new elements. I'm not sure if this actually applies to when the addition/removal can be at any position in the list.

If I am correct, the linked list will operate like this; It will find the position of the node that needs to be added/deleted in O(n) time, then add/remove the node in O(1), giving an overall time of O(n).

In an array; Due to random access memory, it will find the position of the node that needs to be added/deleted in O(1) time, then add/delete the node in O(n) time due to potentially needing to move all the data of the array (assuming deleting means to move all nodes after it back 1). Thus giving an overall operation time of O(n)

From that, there doesnt seem to be a clear advantage in either. If I look at average case, the linked list would take on average n/2 operations on average, as the node will on average be in the middle of the list.

As for the array, deleting would also take average n/2 operations for similiar reasons, while adding would take n operations if it needs to move all the data to accommodate the extra element, or n/2 if there is enough room and needs to move the data up 1 space. Would this give an average of 2*n/3, and could that possibly be a reason as to why a linked list will be better for this?

Comment: Both are *O(n)* if you do not have access to the node itself. The linked list takes *O(n)* in finding the node, whereas the array takes *O(n)* for shifting remaining elements to the left.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So neither are better, given we can't make any more assumptions?

Comment: if the index is typically small compared to the size of the list, a linked list can be better, if the index is more at the end of the list, then an array is better.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well that is an additional assumption. It seems on average, the array is bounded below by n/2, and above by 3n/4, while the linked list will always have an average of n/2. The best case is O(1), so thats not too useful.

Comment: Your mileage will vary, but bear in mind arrays are much friendlier to the cache than linked lists.  Herb Sutter did a fantastic talk where he covered this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJHgp1ugKGM (skip to about 29:27 if you want to get to the good stuff).

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO! Interesting question.
I think you are right, that both operations are O(n) as long as the array can be extended, without allocating new memory.
But if new memory had to be allocated, the question is what would happen then.
In your question you assume that one had to allocate memory for the new full size array. But this might not be true.
I am not an operating systems expert, but I could imaging the following situation:
The memory is partitioned into pages. If the current nr of pages (n) are not enough to store the new array after an insert, one needs n+1 pages for the new array.
In this case - if I was an operating systems programmer - I would not allocate newly n+1 pages and copy the whole array with O(n) to the new memory, but I would allocate just one more page, and set up the virtual memory so that the old pages and the new pages are continuous in virtual memory, even if the are discontinuous in physical memory.
In this case, the situation is the same as if no new memory had to be allocated (considering the O notation).
To cut it short, I believe both implementations are O(n).